# How choose audio fingerprint algorithm to create a cooperative music database?

Tags: audio-fingerprinting, audioflinger

I need to create a cooperative music identification service. Every user will have an option to fingerprint a song and send it to the server with its meta information. At the beginning the service database will be empty and every time a music fingerprint will be received meta data for the song will be updated (the server will assign meta data to a finger print based on majority choise if different user will send different information for the same fingerprint).

I need to calculate a fingerprint for the whole song, I do not need to identify a song from just a fraction.

The fingerprint should not be 100% accurate. I will be happy if two song file will receive the same fingerprint just if the same file is encoded with different compression rate. A low level of noise independence will be a plus.

Silence at the begining or the end of the song will be not a problem, I should remove them using standard silence suppression algorithm (and also in this case a do not need very precise result).

I know there are some opensource library like: http://echoprint.me/ and https://acoustid.org/ but these libraries are excessive for my needs, because if I understood correctly they can identify a song from just a part, and this will create a heavy database. I need an algorithm that will give me a not too heavy (some kb) fingerprint for the whole song.

Which is the simplest and fastest algorithm I can use?

Thanks to all

Comment: This problem is actually far more complicated than it seems. Google invested quite a lot into their content ID algorithm which does that for music used in videos. It is still known for being quite inaccurate from time to time.

Comment: Maybe this [Audio Fingerprinting software written in c# /NET](https://github.com/nelemans1971/AudioFingerprinting) helps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [AcoustID](https://acoustid.org/) project. Your description matches this project on a lot of points. Only some of their approaches are different from what you suggest.

> Can the service identify short audio snippets?
>
> No, it can't. The service has been designed for identifying full audio
>   files. We would like to eventually support also this use case, but
>   it's not a priority at the moment. Note that even when this will be
>   implemented, it will be still intended for matching the original audio
>   (e.g. for the purpose of tracklisting a long audio stream), not audio
>   with background noise recorded on a phone.

Have a look at their mailing list for some better explanations: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/acoustid